# Como ingresar una opción de continuar dentro de un ciclo for

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un código de este tipo y dependiendo del numero de amigos (*num_amigos*) que se ingresen en un menú anterior, serán las iteraciones para repetir el menaje. Lo que necesito es poder, después de cada iteración poder tener la opción de salir del ciclo.

```
'for i in range(num_amigos):
nombre_amigo = input("Ingresa el nombre de tu amig@: ")                                         
print(nombre, "dice:", "@"+nombre_amigo, mensaje)    '
```

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías colocar una "señal" al script para poder salir de él. Por ejemplo, voy a simular un ciclo infinito usando `while`, pero tu puedes usar el `for` de la misma manera

```
while True:
    nombre_amigo = input("Ingrese nombre de amig@. [X] para salir: ")
    if nombre_amigo.lower() == 'x':
        break
    print("Hola", nombre_amigo)

print("Has salido")
```

Cuando se cumple la condición, `break` rompe el ciclo `while`. Pasaría lo mismo si fuese un `for`. Si te preguntas, por qué el `print` no está en un `else`, da igual, ya que el `break` hace que se rompa abruptamente el ciclo, evitando la ejecución del código posterior en ese bloque.

Comment: Agradecido, voy a probarlo ahora. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Excelente resultado muchas gracias nuevamente